# adding to a specific cell in JTable is throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 0

Tags: java, swing, jtable

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 0 exception

I created a method to add an object to a specific cell in JTable 
it threw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 0 exception

these are parts of my code

```
    //creating a JTable and a table model
    horaireTable = new JTable();
    modelHT = new DefaultTableModel();
    modelHT.setColumnIdentifiers(rowHead);
    horaireTable.setModel(modelHT);
    horaireTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    horaireTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(106);
    horaireTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(107);
    horaireTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(106);
    horaireTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(107);
    horaireTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(106);
    horaireTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMinWidth(107);
    horaireTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMinWidth(106);

    JScrollPane paneHT = new JScrollPane(horaireTable);

    paneHT.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 130));

    //getting data to add
    int j,s;

    j = listJours.getSelectedIndex();  //listJours and listSeance are two 
    s = listSeance.getSelectedIndex(); // Jlists containing strings
    String h ="exemple";

    //adding to the table
    modelHT.setValueAt(h,s,j);
```

the result I get is a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 0 exception

Comment: Seems you try to access something that is not there. Can you post your code in a way every variable is declared and initialized so someone else can try it.

Comment: @chris01 my code contains a lot of variable from other classes its very hard to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the result I get is a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 0 exception

You are trying to update a cell in the TableModel that does not exist.

```
modelHT = new DefaultTableModel();
```

You created an empty TableModel with 0 row and 0 columns.

```
modelHT.setColumnIdentifiers(rowHead);
```

You then add 7 column headers to the table but you still have 0 rows of data.

```
modelHT.setValueAt(h,s,j);
```

You can't just set the value of a cell if it doesn't exist in the model.

If you want to change data in a cell then the data must exist in the TableModel.

One way to do this is to create a TableModel with a define number of row and columns:

```
//modelHT = new DefaultTableModel();
modelHT = new DefaultTableModel(rowHead, 5);
```

This will create a model with the number of columns specified by your "rowHead" variable and 5 rows of data with null values in each cell.

Another way is to first create a TableModel with only the columns defined, then you dynamically add rows of data as required:

```
modelHT = new DefaultTableModel(rowHead, 0); 
...
modelHT.addRow(...);
```

Comment: `is there a way to create a table model full of null values? ` - already answered. You just need to specify the upper limit.